# Persisting Entities Mapped to MySQL View in JPA/Hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have a entity Customer, which is mapped to a view which is defined as a series of joins between Customer, Account, and Person in my database.

I am using JSF 2.0 with JPA set up with Hibernate. The backing database is MySQL

My question is that given the fact that my Customer entity is mapped to a database view, how will this complicate persisting of new Customer entities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I quote from Adam Bien's book :

"For SQL queries there is no difference between views and tables, so you can easily map a JPA entity to a view transparently. The code on the Java side remains clean and simple – and you will even get better performance. There is a drawback: not all views are updatable. Whether a view is updatable or not highly depends on the complexity and particular database. E.g. in Derby DB all views are not updatable."

http://www.dzone.com/links/r/mapping_jpa_entities_to_sql_views_it_works_even_w.html

Comment: So I probably won't know if my view is updatable until I try, in essence? But in theory it shouldn't cause problems?

Comment: I just updated today a value from a view with oracle database behind,it worked

Comment: I've tried setting up the view, but I cannot set up a @GeneratedValue for the entity's ID but I get an error "Unable to build EntityManagerFactory [...] Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipeCaused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe"

So I'm assuming I'll need to generate the ID's in an entity mapped directly to the database table, and just update through the view, no? (Sorry, I'm new to this database stuff)

Comment: Using MySQL, I had a model mapped to a view which was a simple SELECT * FROM model_table, and `modelDAO.save(model)` updated the view as well as the underlying model_table ... Seemed odd to me